# Java UCanAccess JDBC Preparedstatement parameter index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am trying to make a simple Select Statement from an Acess-Database. I would like to select all Rows where the column Name contains a searched name. I am using the LIKE Operator with the *-Wildcard insted of the usual % Wildcard because Access works with *. However, if I want to execute the program,  It throws an exception `Invalid argument in JDBC call: parameter index out of range: 1`. I tried to debug and it seems like when the prepared Statement is created, the ? in the sql-String is transformed to a _ and the PreparedStatement has no parameters anymore. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Heres the full code:

```
        
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        String prepStmtString = "SELECT Name FROM Kunde WHERE Name LIKE \"*?*\"";
        
        try {
            PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(prepStmtString);
            
            prepStmt.setString(1, name);
            
            ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                names.add(rs.getString("Name"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return names;
    }
```

The connection to the Database works fine and I also tried it with the normal Statement and executeQuery(String sql) method and it worked.

Comment: Wildcard queries are not normally usable with bind variables, irrespective of database. You need a standard `Statement` with that. I'd probably use `String.format` to construct it

Comment: Your query does **not** have a parameter, it has a string literal containing a question mark. It would be a parameter in `LIKE ?` or `LIKE "*" || ? || "*"` (or whatever the syntax for string concatenation is in Access).

Comment: @g00se wild card queries work fine with bind variables, but then you actually need to pass a bind variable, not a string literal containing a question mark.

Comment: What I was getting at is that I'm thinking (though can't find a source at the moment) that the optimisation behind the procedure of 'preparing' statements cannot properly occur where wildcards are involved, but you can of course use a PreparedStatement wherever you want. So `setString("*" + name + "*");` (code that could be used here with `LIKE ?`) will of course 'work' but will be no more optimised than a `Statement`. I'm not 100% sure about this though